# Hover animation on a button ends up hiding the text - how do I fix this?

Tags: html, css

This is what my HTML code looks like:

```
<div class="container">
   <div id="buttoncontainer">
      <button class="button">Registruj se</button>
   </div>
 </div>
```

I followed a YouTube tutorial trying to do a hover animation which changes the color of the button from left to right. This is what the CSS code looks like:

```
.button {
    background: transparent;
    color: #ffffff;
    height: 45px;
    width: 150px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.button::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 0%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #1bb793;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    border-radius: 5px;
    z-index: 0;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

.button:hover:before {
    width: 100%;
}

#buttoncontainer {
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #17161a;
    height: 45px;
    width: 150px;
}
```

The color of the button does change, but the letters disappear behind it.

The tutorial showed it with a transparent background when I needed a black one so that's why I added the div around the button and made its background black. How do I fix this so that the letters on the button stay visible?

Comment: `z-index: -1;` for your before element, and `z-index: 0` for #buttoncontainer.